# How to sort a vector using std::views C++20 feature?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, std-ranges

I want to loop through a vector in a sorted way **without modifying the underlying vector**.

Can `std::views` and/or `std::range` be used for this purpose?

I've successfully implemented filtering using `views`, but I don't know if it is possible to sort using a predicate.

You can find an example to complete here : https://godbolt.org/z/cKer8frvq

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

struct Data{
    int a;
};

int main() {

    std::vector<Data> vec = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {10}, {5}, {6}};
  
    auto sortedView = // <= can we use std::views here ?
                           
    for (const auto &sortedData: sortedView) std::cout << std::to_string(sortedData.a) << std::endl; // 1 2 3 5 6 10

    for (const auto &data: vec) std::cout << std::to_string(data.a) << std::endl; // 1 2 3 10 5 6
}
```

Comment: [OT]: `std::to_string` is unneded, `std::cout << data.a` is correct.

Comment: This vector can hold about 1GB of data...so I'd rather not copying it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to modify *something* to use `std::ranges::sort` (or `std::sort`), but it doesn't have to be your actual data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

struct Data{
    int a;
    friend auto operator<=> (const Data &, const Data &) = default;
};

int main() {

    std::vector<Data> vec = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {10}, {5}, {6}};

    std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(vec.size());
    std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), std::size_t{ 0 }); // 0z in C++23

    auto proj = [&vec](std::size_t i) -> Data & { return vec[i]; };

    std::ranges::sort(indexes, std::less<>{}, proj);
  
    auto sortedView = std::ranges::views::transform(indexes, proj);
                           
    for (const auto &sortedData: sortedView) std::cout << sortedData.a << std::endl; // 1 2 3 5 6 10

    for (const auto &data: vec) std::cout << data.a << std::endl; // 1 2 3 10 5 6
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this line in detail please? : `auto proj = [&vec](std::size_t i) -> Data & { return vec[i]; };`

Comment: @Victor: See [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (with capture and trailling return type).

Comment: @Jarod42 it's actually the `Data & { return vec[i]; }` return type that I don't understand right now

Comment: @Victor: `-> Data&` is trailing return type. (without that it would return by value).