# How to use std::ranges::set_symmetric_difference over a non sorted range?

Tags: c++, vector, view, range

I have two vectors `a` and `b` and I need to iterate over every element that is NOT in both of them. So I decided to use std::ranges::set_symmetric_difference. To my dismay, this requires the vectors to be sorted, which they are not.

How can I, without sorting the vectors, create a range that contains the symmetric difference of the two sets?

Example code:

```
std::vector<int> a = {5, 3, 4, 1, 2};
std::vector<int> b = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
std::vector<int> c;

std::ranges::set_symmetric_difference(a, b, std::back_inserter(c));
std::ranges::for_each(c, [](const int i)
{
   std::cout << i << std::endl; 
});
```

This works fine if I sort a, but in my case I cannot.

Restriction: I can easily just iterate over the larger once and use a if check to skip any that are in the smaller one using `std::ranges::contains`. I do not want to do that. I want to iterate over one container or view or range that I can iterate over every element of without worry of running into one of the duplicated elements.

Bonus points if I do not need a vector `c`.

Comment: why do you not want to sort the vectors? Trivially finding the elements is O(N^2). By sorting the vectors it gets faster and simpler

Comment: Well, worst case I would use `std::set::insert` for each element in `a` and `b` and I have a symmetric difference. I was hoping to do this entirely with views and ranges so I do not need another container entirely.

Comment: I am not into ranges. When I search for getting a sorted view, I find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71348675/how-to-sort-a-vector-using-stdviews-c20-feature. At least it explains that you dont need to sort the actual container, but only a container of indices. Not great, but in case `int` is just simplified for your example, it might be something for you

Comment: Unfortunately, they only manage to not sort the vector, they still do sort. Its just that they sort a range. Unfortunately, I am trying to avoid sorting altogether.

Comment: Why are you so opposed to sorting? Do you realize creating a `std::set` is essentially sorting + some more? Is this some nonsense requirement from homework or competitive programming?